# google SMTP is giving error on sending mail

Tags: python, django, gmail, email

I am using python Django to send mail to a user when user login and using django.core.mail(send mail) but it's working on localhost and successfully sending emails to the user but when I host my site on  Heroku it's giving some errors.

**settings.py**

```
# email config
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'  # During deployment only
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_USER_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Masjid Matrimonial Team <noreply@example.com>'
```

**Views.py**

```
currenttime=datetime.now()
subject = "New Login Alert"
message="You have loged into your account on "+ currenttime.strftime('%A %d %B,%Y %I:%M %p')
recipient_list = [useris.appuser.email]
send_mail( subject, message, email_from, recipient_list )email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Can you share the errors?

Comment: this is the error I am facing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TvqaJ8xr_5BJReOQigYlKUFgjv1rbbep/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

SMTP Error code 534 5.7.14 means Authorization error.

Try to activate sending via less secure apps via https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: it is activated

Comment: Did you also try https://g.co/allowaccess and https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha ? Please check also https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563

Comment: no that was not enabled thank you very much it's working now

Comment: @IrtazaHussain you should accept this as the answer if it is working.